# Electrical resistance of sodium chloride solutions with varying temperature

Tags: temperature, electrical-resistance, electrochemistry

I am doing an experiment where if I try to increase the temperature of the sodium chloride solution I have and then measure resistance, I would expect that the resistance will increase as there are more collusion between particles due to increase in temperature. However according to the equipment's readings, the resistance seems to be smaller and falls as temperature gets larger.

Now I do not know if this is an equipment anomaly or my theory isn't on par with the observations. Could anyone explain to me why the resistance of the sodium chloride solution will decrease as the temperature of the solution is increased?

Comment: First and foremost, check your equipment and repeat your experiments.

Comment: Always consider all resistances, including the source, leads, and—most importantly—charge transfer at the electrodes. You might be conducting an electrochemistry experiment instead of a conductance experiment.

Comment: Acc. this study https://www.hilarispublisher.com/open-access/temperature-effects-on-conductivity-of-seawater-and-physiologic-salinemechanism-and-significance-2150-3494-1000109.pdf the **conductivity** of seawater *increases* with temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the temperature increases, the viscosity of your solution decreases which gives the ions in solution (the actual charge carriers) more mobility. This increase in carrier mobility lowers the resistance.